# How to install fedora's phoneshell in old touchscreen tablets and old touchscreen phones

Tags: hardware

Explain step-by-step procedure on how to install the fedora's phoneshell in old touchscreen tablets and old touchscreen smartphones suitable for both a techie and a non-techie

Comment: Please do not write the question into the title, the title is for summarizing your question. Furthermore you "demand" a solution but don't give us any details (no tablet model name, only "old touchscreen" which doesn't allow to understand what devices you are talking about). So please edit your question and describe those things in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [Fedora Phosh](https://fedoraproject.org/spins/phosh/), which is part of the [Fedora Mobility](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mobility) project?

If so, that only supports very "open" devices, such as [Purism librem 5, and the Pine series of phones and tablets](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mobility#Supported_devices).

Phosh isn't a GUI for Android, nor a means of using a mobile device to control a computer running Fedora. It's a GUI for Fedora Linux running on a mobile device, more suitable for small screens than the default Fedora GUIs. This requires that the whole OS on the device be Linux, rather than Android.